# setting up cluster between different datacenter in cassandra using apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We have three node cluster in the same datacenter configured using private ip and every thing is working fine . We wanted to add the DR for this node.When we try to add the node using seed node as public-IP we are getting error as

**ERROR [main] 2017-12-04 02:35:12,329 CassandraDaemon.java:747 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any seeds**

Can someone help me with adding the node to the cluster which is on different data center?

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configMultiNetworks.html

Answer (score 0):

For the node in new DC:

- Set the **seeds** value in *cassandra.yaml* to your seeds in your first DC. If you already have multiple DCs make sure to add seeds from those as well. You should have 2 seeds per DC.
- Change **endpoint_snitch** value in *cassandra.yaml* to a snitch that supports multiple DCs. E.g. GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
- Set **dc** value in *cassandra-rackdc.properties*.

Comment: We are using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch and this is the first new node and in the new datacenter. 
in cassandra-rackdc.properties (on primary node)

dc=PRIMARY
rack=RAC1
in cassandra-rackdc.properties (on new DR node)

dc=SECONDARY
rack=RAC2

Comment: Did you change all the other values as well?

Comment: what are the other values we need to change

Comment: You said you changed dc value and endpoint_snitch. But did you set the seeds property properly? Otherwise this looks like a network issue where your new node is unable to connect to the seed on PRIMARY dc. You should use telnet to test connecting to the seed on PRIMARY dc on port 7000 or 7001 (tls)

Comment: telnet primary-public-ip-address 7000 is working fine. but in Cassandra.yaml file we have given seeds =primary-public-ip-address  we are getting error as unable to gossip with seed node